# error obj\Debug\android\bin\packaged_resources in xamarin.android

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I'm using a .aar file of android developed in native android(java). Now I want to use it in my xamairn.android project. I have created a .dll file from .aar file and added it into my xamarin.android project. But when I am trying to build my project I am getting following error:

> The file "obj\Debug\android\bin\packaged_resources" does not exist.

I tried lot of solutions for it but nothing works. Does anyone have idea what is the real cause of this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you've lost the resource files from your .aar lib when you convert it to .dll, not sure how did you create the .dll file from your .aar lib, but you may follow up [Binding an .AAR](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/binding-an-aar/) to create a binding library.

Make sure the `Build Action` for the lib is `LibraryProjectZip`.

Comment: Yes we are doing the build action for the lib is LIbraryProjectZip, but still we are getting the error

Comment: @anand, are you sure this issue happens when you add .dll to your project? Did you tried to remove this dll and rebuild your project? There're too many possibilities to cause this exception.